Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a differentiable, bounded function. Prove that $f(c) f^{\prime}(c)=c$, for some real number $c$.

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a differentiable, bounded function. Prove that $f(c) f^{\prime}(c)=c$, for some real number $c$.

My approach : considering $g(x)=f(x)^2-x^2$, I want to use Rolle's theorem to somehow get $g(a)=g(b)$. As the function is bounded, I feel there will exist $a$ and $b$ for which $f(a)=f(b)$. I dont know how I will extend it to $g(x)$.

$\arctan$ is bounded, but $f(a)\neq f(b)$ for all $a\neq b$

You are on the right track with the choice of the function $g$. $f$ is bounded so that $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} g(x) = -\infty$. If you choose any $y < g(0)$ then there exist $x_1 < 0$ and $x_2 > 0$ with
$$
 g(x_1) < y < g(0) \\
 g(x_2) < y < g(0) \\
$$
so that $g(a) = g(b) = y$ for some $a < 0$ and some $b > 0$ by the intermediate value theorem.
Then
$$
 g'(c) = 2f(c)f'(c) - 2c = 0
$$
for some $c \in (a, b)$ by Rolle's theorem.

I think it is more direct to say that since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}g(x)=-\infty$, then $g$ achieves a maximum at some point $c\in\mathbb{R}$, hence $g'(c)=0$, namely $f(c)f'(c)=c$. ($+1$ anyway)

@ecrin: I wanted to demonstrate how OP's idea “... I want to use Rolle's theorem ...” can be realized, but yes of course, that is also a neat argument. Perhaps you want to post it as an answer?

Your choice of $g$ is ideal.
It holds that $\lim_{x \rightarrow\pm \infty} g(x) = -\infty$. Then, the sets
$$
N_b := \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}: g(x) \geq g(b) \rbrace
$$
for every $b \in \mathbb{R}$, i are compact: Closedness immediately follows from continuity of $g$. If they were not bounded, there would be a sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq N_b$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \lvert x_k  \rvert = \infty$. But then $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g(x_k) = -\infty$ which contradicts the sequence $(x_k)$ living in $N_b$.
This compactness combined with continuity of $g$ implies existence of a global maximal point of $g$ which is your desired point $c$ (which can be seen after differentiation).

If $g(0) = 0$, then you're done by taking $c=0$.
Suppose $f(0)^2 > 0$. Since $f$ is bounded choose $a > 0$ large enough so that $g(a) < 0$ and similar $b < 0$ such that $g(b) < 0$. Now intermediate value theorem will give $x_1 \in (b, 0)$ and $x_2 \in (0, a)$ such that $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$. Thus by Rolle's theorem you get $c \in (x_1, x_2)$ satisfying desired property.

Just saw after posting this answer that @MartinR has already provided the same ans.
